# Making a desired layout in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, button, oscilloscope

I am working on the layout of the android app but i have found that all buttons are fixed in a column in Eclipse atuomatically. What should i do to make it to the desired position like the app shown in the link?? thanks

http://www.dcemu.co.uk/vbulletin/threads/335622-Android-oscilloscope

Comment: read about relative layouts: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html , also you can google for examples - there are great solutions :) Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` in the `main.xml` file.
In this layout, you can place the components at any place in the layout, but the components are placed `relatively` to one another.
You can use a mixture of layout to make your view look sound. Also try using the Layout Orientation i.e. either Vertical or horizontal,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get 2 columns of buttons by having a vertical `LinearLayout` containing several horizontal `LinearLayout`s, each containing 2 buttons. Give the buttons equal weights to space them evenly, and some margin to make them look less cluttered.

E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 3" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 4" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or if the columns were going to be very long, you could use a horizontal linear layout containing 2 vertical linear layouts, and add the buttons to those.

Or you could use a `TableLayout` with 2 columns and have `TableRows` containing the buttons (I generally find table layouts harder to work with, perhaps that's just me).

I find it easier to write the xml in Eclipse rather than fiddling round with the graphical editor, then just switch over to the graphical editor every now and again to check it displays how you want. Look around online for a few example layouts and you'll soon get the idea.

To emulate that layout exactly, start with a `RelativeLayout` as mihail suggests, and use that to position your other layouts (such as your linear layout with buttons) and views.